# How to add an OR filter around a nested query with elasticsearch-dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a nested filter that looks like this:

```
search = search.filter(
                'nested', 
                path=path, 
                filter=F('bool', must=queries),
                inner_hits={'sort': ['p', 'd']}
            )
```

I'd like to add an OR filter around the whole thing. So it either matches X OR this nested query.

I am using ES 1.7

Comment: where This F is coming From?

Comment: i am unable to import this F from django elasticsearch-dsl

Comment: @SaadMirza you've probably figured it out.  For anyone else with the same question, it appears that `F` was removed in version 2.0.0. The [changelog](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Changelog.html#id32) says to use `Q` instead.

Comment: @user650881 you are right

Answer (score 1):

A little more perseverance got me this:

```
search = search.filter(
                'or',
                [F(
                    'nested',
                    path=path,
                    filter=F('bool', must=queries),
                    inner_hits={'sort': ['p', 'd']}
                ), F('bool', must=or_queries)]
            )
```

Which seems to do the trick..